# How to allow textbox to take only numbers in extjs

Tags: extjs

User should be prevented from entering text to datefield. they should only be able to enter  numbers in extjs.

```
var dateConfig = {
            width: 80,
            enableKeyEvents: true,
            identity: identity,
            format: dateFormat,
            emptyText: visibleDtFormat,
            maskRe: /[0-9.-]/,
            listeners: selectlisteners
        };
```

Comment: Which version and variant of ExtJS?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `maskRe: /[0-9.-]/,` config to restrict text. Below is working code of extJS 6. Please have a look.

Here is example of two `datefield`. One is without reg exp where you can insert text and other with reg exp where you can enter text. It is restricted to only numbers.

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 300,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    title: 'Dates',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'datefield',
        anchor: '100%',
        fieldLabel: 'From',
        name: 'from_date',
        maskRe: /[0-9.-]/,
        maxValue: new Date()  // limited to the current date or prior
    }, {
        xtype: 'datefield',
        anchor: '100%',
        fieldLabel: 'To',
        name: 'to_date',
        value: new Date()  // defaults to today
    }]
});
```

Comment: He did supply a ```maskRe```. Also, ```datefield``` doesn't mention maskRe in the documentation for 6.5 in which, in fact, your code has no effect for the purposes of this question. Your code will work on the version you stated in your post on the other hand, so it does add value to this thread.
Please modify your post to explain that the code won't work with more modern versions of ExtJS... and let's ask the version of ExtJS he is trying to run his code against. If you wish, then, you can add examples for other versions of ExtJS to complete your answer.

Comment: this code will work smoothly on classic. OP is not using modern because he is giving  `enableKeyEvents` in config. `enableKeyEvents` is not present in modern doc. correct me if I am wrong. For modern we need to do pattern and since the question looks like classic so i didn't went that way.

Comment: You're right. I completely forgot to select "classic" in the sencha docs. Nevermind my comment, your code works just fine on 6.5 classic. I still wonder why it's not working for him with ```maskRe``` though. Let's see what he says...